# Opening a AAC/h264 file in Sony Vegas Movie Studio HD Platinum 11.0

Tags: video-encoding, video-codecs, sony-vegas

I have encoded some videos using mencoder, with AAC and h.264. Sony vegas cannot open the files, without any explanation. Here is what Gspot tells me about the videos :

[image]

To encode the videos I have used :

```
-oac faac -faacopts br=160:mpeg=4:object=2 -srate 48000 -channels 2
-ovc x264 -x264encopts pass=1:preset=slow:keyint=200:crf=19:level_idc=31:colormatrix=bt709
sourceVideo.avi -o destinationVideo.mp4
```

***previous edits :***

The obvious problem seems to be the AAC codec, but I cannot find it. I've included it as a dll in mencoder, but I can't seem to find it for windows.

EDIT: I've read that AAC encoder need a licence, but here I'm only trying to *read* it in Vegas...

EDIT2 : I have tried installing the K-Lite codec pack, no change. Sony Vegas cannot open a file encoded with h264, neither can it read audio encoded in AAC. Is this normal ?

Comment: I have re-encoded the audio as mp3, but Vegas still refuses to open it :(

Comment: I cannot open either xvid/aac or 264/mp3

Comment: Try to install a serious codec pack such as K-Lite.

Comment: No, it didn't help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the 64 bits version of Vegas Pro can't use 32 bits codecs so maybe this is your problem.

Some people recommand to install both versions of Sony Vegas (32 bits and 64 bits).
Also, it seems that there are several codec packs depending on the version you use :

> [Win7codecs](http://majorgeeks.com/Win7codecs_d5959.html) works for 32bit vegas and [x64codecs](http://majorgeeks.com/download.php?det=5535) works for 64bit vegas

Comment: Moreover, someone has a similar issue [here](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/333574-Codec-Conflicting-Issues). "Ah, I fixed it! What I did was uninstall all codecs, went into CCleaner64 and fixed registry files and uninstalled the codecs from there. Then I went and re-downloaded Win7Codec Pack v279, along with x64Components_v283. Installed these and my files can be seen again in Vegas!"

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this AAC ACM codec:

http://fcchandler.home.comcast.net/~fcchandler/index.html

> I have re-encoded the audio as mp3, but Vegas still refuses to open it

Encoder and Decoder are 2 different, often separate things. Just because you can encode it in mp3, doesn't mean you can decode it.

For mp3 there's an encoder AND decoder.

Comment: I have created 4 video files, combinations of AAC-mp3 and h264-xvid. Vegas can only open the xvid/mp3

Comment: If you can't open the h264, something is wrong with your h264 codec. I always use this x264 build: http://komisar.gin.by/

Answer (score 0):

I see that the audio codec is [FAAD AAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAAD2#FAAD2_decoder). K-Lite has AAC, but I'm not sure about the FAAD variant.

The only codec I was able to find for you to try is [CoreAAC Directshow filter](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/coreaac_directshow_filter.htm) (dating from 2006 but worth trying). Reboot before trying, just in case.

VLC has its own codecs, so this is why it works.

Comment: I installed the K-lite codec pack, now g-spot confirms that both a 264 and a aac decoder are present. Yet Vegas refuses to open them.

Comment: Try to install in addition the CoreAAC Directshow filter.

Comment: Didn't help either.

Comment: You could try to install in addition [K-Lite Codec Pack 64-bit](http://www.codecguide.com/klcp_64bit.htm). If this doesn't help, could you post one small problematic file ?

Comment: http://dl.free.fr/rH5ltl9RO

Comment: Strange: This works OK on my computer, using the ffdshow decoder. Try to install the [latest version](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/FFDShow.htm). Note that the sound was really weak so I had to turn up my speaker. Try also to rename the .mp4 to .avi.

Comment: You can open them in vegas ? Which version ? I only have the "Movie Studio HD Platinum 11.0"

Comment: I played using Windows Media Player, did you try it? I have K-Lite Mega installed, and during installation I have chosen all the VFW codecs.